# Using v-show on root component by child data

Tags: vue.js

In my root component, I have a channels component and in that component, there is a boolean value that I want my root component to be displayed regarding the value. Is there a way to achieve that aim? I have tried using children value but it didn't even render the root component. My root component :

```
<template>
  <div id="app" v-show="!$children[0].isPlayerOpen">
    <Channels/>
  </div>
</template>
```

My channels component :

```
data() {
    return {
      ..
      isPlayerOpen:false,
      ..
    };
  }
```

Comment: You can emit an event from child to your parent and then toggle in handler function. 
Do note, the default value of `isPlayerOpen` has to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root / parent component

```
<template>
  <!-- [6] use the data property to show / hide component in v-show directive -->
  <div id="app" v-show="showChannel">
    <!-- [3] Collect the emitted event & attach a handler to it -->
    <!-- [4] So, if an event is emitted, attached handler will be called -->
    <Channels 
      @on-change-is-player-open-value="handleOnChangeIsPlayerOpenValue"
    />
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      showChannel: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // [5] In events handler, set the new value for the data property that has come form the child
    handleOnChangeIsPlayerOpenValue (newValue) {
      this.showChannel = newvalue
    }
  }
}
```

Channels / child component

```
export default {
  watch: {
    isPlayerOpen: { // [1] watch `isPlayerOpen` in child component, if it changes below handler will be called
      handler (newValue) {
        this.$emit('on-change-is-player-open-value', newValue) // [2] emit an event
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @AEB https://medium.com/js-dojo/component-communication-in-vue-js-ca8b591d7efa child-parent communication in Vue

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me out. Could it be handled by computed property too?

Comment: Child to parent communication is nothing to do with the computed property, so no. But, if you are asking to use a computed property instead of the watcher I would still suggest no, as a computed is intended to return something by reducing / filtering etc rather than doing some operation

Comment: Thanks again. By the way, is there a way to achieve a components data from an unrelated component?

Comment: yes, we can create an `event bus` to transfer data between two unrelated components